# How to check an array that it contains equal number of characters or not using Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I have an array like this `['n','n','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s']` and I want to check if there are equal counts of characters or not. In the above one I have 6 `n`s and 4 `s`s and so they are not equal and I tried, but nothing went correct. How can I do this using  Ruby?

Comment: Are you after something like this: `arr.count('n') == arr.count('s')`?

Comment: What **exactly** did you try and went incorrect?

Comment: actually I'm trying to count total number of n S and s S and then to check equal or not

Answer (score 1):

Given array:

```
a = ['n','n','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s']
```

Group array by it's elements and take only values of this group:

```
(f,s) = a.group_by{|e| e}.values
```

Compare sizes:

```
f.size == s.size
```

Result: `false`

Comment: Good one. If its more than two character classes, use something `groups = a.group...`; `groups.map(&:count).uniq.count == 1` - this misdetects single sets (`a = ['s']`) and is not super-readable, but should work otherwise.

Comment: @Felix looks like we had the same idea, except I hadn't noticed the issue with single sets, so I have updated my answer- thanks.

Comment: @sagarpandya82: Not really, you come 'around the other corner': uniqing the array first and then count. I first group/count and then uniq. I like Yevgeniys code better (to my eyes it reads easier), but yours is more robust, so far :) .

Comment: Thanks @Yengeniy I would like to know for different characters in the same array for example `['n' , 'n' , 't' , 's' , 'n' , 't' , 's' , 's' , 't']` and more like that so is it a better way ?

Comment: I suggest you remove `(f,s) = ` (btw, `f,s =` is sufficient) and tack on `.map(&:size).uniq.size == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this:

```
x = ['n','n','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s']
x.group_by {|c| c}.values.map(&:size).inject(:==)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for something like this:

```
def eq_num? arr
  return false if arr.size == 1
  arr.uniq.map {|i| arr.count(i)}.uniq.size == 1
end

arr = ['n','n','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s'] 
eq_num? arr #=> false

arr = ['n','n','n','s','n','s','s','s']
eq_num? arr #=> true
```

Works for more than two kinds of letters too:

```
arr = ['n','n','t','s','n','t','s','s','t']
eq_num? arr #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-count) is relatively inefficient as it requires a full pass through the array for each element whose instances are being counted. Instead use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), as others have done, or use a counting hash, as below (see [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new)):

**Code**

```
def equal_counts?(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s] += 1 }.values.uniq.size == 1
end
```

**Examples**

```
equal_counts? ['n','n','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s']
  #=> false
equal_counts? ['n','r','r','n','s','s','n','s','r']
  #=> true
```

**Explanation**

For

```
arr = ['n','n','n','s','n','s','n','s','n','s']
```

the steps are as follows.

```
h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s] += 1 }
  #=> {"n"=>6, "s"=>4} 
a = h.values
  #=> [6, 4]
b = a.uniq
  #=> [6, 4]
b.size == 1
  #=> false
```